# How to fix access an instance of EditText with "findViewById()" method located on a sub layout in navigation bar app?

Tags: java, android, input, android-edittext

I'm creating an Android app and in MainActivity class I've come to a problem with implementation of a part of algorithm. My problem is how to make xml file id visible in MainActivity with navigation bar layout being the xml layout file added in method "setContentView()" because the app is organised as Navigation bar layout with inside layouts and one of those layouts contains EditText classes?

I really need access to that text box in MainActivity class and can't find a way to do so.

In provided code, I want to access them by calling methods finViewById() marked in comment with 1. and 2.

XML files are activity_main, input_layout and setting_layout.
Activity_main is a navigation bar layout and other layouts are showed with fragment calling.

I've tried including it into the main activity xml file and it did help solving the problem even though it is not a solution I want.

```
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

    input = findViewById(R.id.text1); //1.
    output = findViewById(R.id.text_output); //2.

    input.addTextChangedListener(new TextWatcher() {
        @Override
        public void beforeTextChanged(CharSequence s, int start, int count, int after) {

        }

        @Override
        public void onTextChanged(CharSequence s, int start, int before, int count) {

        }

        @Override
        public void afterTextChanged(Editable s) {

        }
    });
    BottomNavigationView navigation = (BottomNavigationView) findViewById(R.id.navigation);
    navigation.setOnNavigationItemSelectedListener(mOnNavigationItemSelectedListener);
}
```

Comment: If those `TextView`s are in a `Fragment`, you should be handling them in the `Fragment`. You can pass any data needed in `MainActivity` through some other mechanism; e.g., interfaces, etc.

Answer (score 0):

If the view is inside the `BottomNavigationView`, I think you can use

```
navigation.findViewById(R.id.YOUR_VIEW_ID);
```

to get it.